# Example for stationary time series

Tags: statistics, covariance, time-series

I'm reading a book about time series analysis where an example for stationary is given:

$X_n$ independent with $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ if i is odd and $P(X = 1) = P(X = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$, if i is even.

$E[X_i] = 0$ for all i, which is clear.

What I don't understand is that $Cov(X_t, X_{t+h}) = 0$ for $h \neq 0$ and $= 1$ for $h = 0$.

How do I get this solution? Thanks!

Comment: For $h = 0$ I hope it is trivial for you ($\operatorname{Cov}(X_t,X_t)$). For $h \ne 0$, you should just use that you have defined $X_n$ to be independent. Remember that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both cases, you can get the results by using the definition of the covariance, $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X] E[Y]$.

For the case of $h=0$ you might notice that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X) = \operatorname{Var}(X)$ from the above. For the $h\ne 0$ case, use the independence. When two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$.